# How can I find removed questions tagged "books"?

Tags: support, tags, deleted-questions

A month ago I brought up all SO questions tagged `books`, with a plan of putting together a reading list.  I was uneasy that those questions were all closed.  Now the tag has been removed, and I notice that several book-related questions can also be removed.

Without going into the merits of the removal, does anyone know how I can peer into the past and find the questions formerly tagged `books`, preferably sorted by number of upvotes?

Comment: The data dumps are snapshots at fixed points in time so would contain that information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I put this query together that'll get you some of the way there: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/120564/questions-that-were-once-tagged-books.

It doesn't include deleted questions because they are no longer available in the data explorer.

Comment: Quite useful, I forked that to just use `##TagName##` - because time traveling is useful way beyond books. Now to get even more freaky, it took 6666 ms to return a query for 66 posts [tagged computer](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/120591/questions-that-were-once-tagged-tag?TagName=computer). Clearly, I have revealed the meta tag of the beast.

Comment: This is brilliant.  In addition to my upvote and check mark, you have my thanks!  (I never knew about data.stackexchange.com!)